# Android Animation from images lag

Tags: android, image, animation, lag

I have 90 images with 480x526 dimension, ~20KB/image (i got from designer) and i need to play animation from images. First i tried AnimationDrawable but it is giving me out of memory error. After that I tired this solution:

[Android: make animation from still images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611123/android-make-animation-from-still-images)

It's working, but sometimes smooth sometimes lagging, (it's seems to be skip x pictures) Which is a best solution for animation? Thanks

Comment: if you are executing the animtion on the emulator , try to edit your emulator setting to increase the memory for it , or you can tried it on a Device , you will not get that problem i think

Comment: and the last update of the android sdk , they have added a new emulator which works with native code , so the execution on it is too fast without previous problems that we got on the current emulators : to know more about that  : visit this link : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/updated-sdk-tools-and-adt-revision-17.html