# How to Animate different Set Of Image in an ImageView Android

Tags: android

Hello guy'z I am new to android and I am working on a fitness app in which I have around 100 exercise and for each exercise I have around 10-15 images. The number of images vary depending on the exercises.

I want to animate those images so is there any library or any api for that. 
I have read the android documentation and found DrawableAnimations https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html

But that does not suit my requirement because I have 100 exercises if I use AnimationDrawable. I have to make 100 xml files containing animationlist for each exercise, 1 file for 1 exercise. So I need help is there any library or any other way to accomplish this task.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look at [**This Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5753031/7130121)